# celery task email not authenticated

Tags: python, flask, smtp, celery

I have a classica flask app structure:

```
> -manage.py
> -celery_runner.py
>- webapp/
> --__init__.py
> --tasks.py
> --config.py
> --extensions.py
```

etc etc

If I enter in manage.py shell and give

```
from webapp.extensions import mail
from flask_mail import Message
from flask import render_template

msg=('test',sender='myadd@host.it', recipients=['myadd@host.it'])
msg.html=('email/welcome.html')

try:
  mail.send(msg)
except:
  print("error")
```

I can send authenticated mail from config retrieved values (it works and they are correct)

```
Received: from mx1.blabla.com (mx1.blabla.com [x.x.x.x])
```

If I send a mail from celery task it result in a:

```
Received: (qmail 22009 invoked by uid 496); 29 Mar 2016 12:21:31 -0000
```

How can I send from celery task authenticated mail as my app already does?
Thx

Comment: How are you initializing Flask-Mail?

Comment: It's initialized in __init__.py with:                                                                          `def create_app(object_name):
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(object_name)

    mail.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(mail_blueprint)

    return app`

Comment: You need to do mail.send()... You should add all this to the question. Also ensure there is a valid app context on the celery side. Otherwise it will not work in the same way. It has to get the config from somewhere

Comment: I had cut the function mai.send(msg) for error it's already present(I edited the question), and I also import current_app but I don't know how to use it to load the config

Comment: I presume `qmail` is the server on your local system?

Comment: Yes, when I send trough webapp normally it works, when it sends trough celery task it's sending trough qmail without authentication(and it doesn't work in gmail for example)

Comment: Right so its simply a config error. Where is the config coming from in the normal app?

Comment: manage.py runserver load launch __init__ that load config from file config.py. I try to create a new app in tasks.py file and duplicate the settings from config.py for mail and now it works so my question is how can I import current_app context in tasks?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/